# Twoside footer produces extra vertical space

Tags: spacing, header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided

The below code produces the correct spacing for odd side pages but incorrect spacing for even side pages.

Correct spacing:

[image]

Wrong spacing:

[image]

In my attempt to optically distinguish between the two declarations, I could find three differences:

1. I declared for the left footer rather than the right.
2. I declared for the footer on the even pages rather than the odd pages.
3. My declaration order is inverse: I start with the `mark` in my first declaration and `\rlap` next to it. The wrong spacing is produced when I issue `\llap` and follow with my `mark`.

I can produce the correct spacing without issuing `\llap`, but I'd really like to have my page number there.

How to get rid of the superfluous space produced by the `\fancyfoot[LE]` declaration? / How to produce the correct spacing on even pages, exactly the same as the spacing on odd pages?

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newlength\titleindent
\setlength\titleindent{.25in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{%
        \leftmark\strut\rlap{\hskip\titleindent\parbox{\titleindent}{\color{blue}\thepage\strut}}%
        }%
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
        \llap{\parbox{\titleindent}{\color{blue}\thepage\strut}}\leftmark\strut%
        }%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As egreg says in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217811/11232), use `\makebox` here also.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newlength\titleindent
\setlength\titleindent{.25in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{%
        \leftmark\strut\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\titleindent}\color{blue}\thepage\strut}%
        }%
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{blue}\thesection\hspace{\titleindent}}\leftmark\strut%
        }%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]