# Aligning a parbox inside titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to produce a document with section numbers in the page margin. I found a pseudo-solution which `llap`s the section numbering to mimic the result. I'm not happy with the way the number and the section align. In fact, I kind of think they don't align at all (see above pictures).

Normally, my go-to method of solving this is by issuing the `\strut` command, but I couldn't figure out a way to do this within the `\titleformat` command.

How can I align them anyway?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\titleindent
\setlength\titleindent{.25in}


\titleformat{\section}% 
  {\normalfont}% 
  {}%
  {0pt}%
  {\llap{\parbox{\titleindent}{\large\thesection\strut\hfill}}\large}%
  []% 



\begin{document}

\section{MMMMmmm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why a `\parbox`?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\titleindent
\setlength\titleindent{.25in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{\thesection\hspace{\titleindent}}}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\section{MMMMmmm}

\end{document}
```

Note that the number should go in the third argument to `\titleformat`, so numberless sections will behave correctly. The global font size should go in the second argument.

[image]

What's the problem with `\parbox`? That its default vertical alignment is `c`; you should have used `\parbox[t]`, but it's a waste of resources: the section number doesn't make a paragraph.